# Onion and garlic dilemma and optimum solution

Tags: shiva-purana, food, rudraksha

Suppose someone has voluntarily gave up onion and garlic. Now he went to a restaurant which also offers no onion and garlic food. So you order food without onion and garlic. Mistakenly restaurant served you food with onion and garlic in it. Now if you complain then food will go to waste and chef will pay for the wastage from his salary and if you eat that then you will feel sinful. What is the right path? Insult food by letting it go waste or go against your belief of not eating onion and garlic. Person can choose to pay and not eat but even then food will be wasted.

Comment: You could just eat the food or give it to a homeless person. You don't really give them up for moral reasons anyway.

Comment: In my locality finding a homeless person after evening is not possible.

Comment: Couldn't you just pack it? What restaurant does not allow packing?

Comment: Well, buffets and Eat as much as you like places. But with buffets you can easily avoid the food you don't want and eat as much as you like places will probably make an exception on account of their mistake.

Comment: I would prefer eating that food & sprinkle Ganges water over my self after returning back.

Comment: A paramahamsa who is so spiritually advanced that their greatest worry is the suffering of others from the karma of serving onion and garlic in error to them is truly a great soul. The answer to this dilemma is that such a parmahamsa should go into the forest and live on nuts and berries so they they not have to worry about the karma that may be inflicted on themselves or others by human interactions.